# iPhone app crash after leaving and returning to app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, crash, geolocation

I have a weird crash in an iPhone app that uses Location Services.  When I leave the app (by pressing the Home button) and immediately return (by clicking the app icon) it gets an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, apparently because an object has become a zombie.

Instruments shows the following history for the offending object:[image: Instruments Zombies display]

All of the callers except the last (the crash) are from framework code (no names in black other than main.m), so I don’t see where the error is coming from.  Am I missing something in Instruments?  I feel that it has a lot of information but maybe I’m looking at the wrong part.

Two other possible hints:

1. I don’t think this happened prior to iOS 5
2. The console shows a spurious message about “adding to memory only” that I don’t recognise/understand:
   [image: Instruments console log]

Any suggestion would be welcome!

The crash occurs when referencing members of locn, an ACLocation object:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)ACLocation *locn;
        emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                        NSLocalizedString(@"%@\nLocation: %@, %@, %@",@"Email text header3"),
                        emailBody,
                        locn.ACLocality,
                        locn.ACAdministrativeArea,
                        locn.ACCountry
                     ];
```

ACLocation is defined as:

```
@interface ACLocation : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>  {
    double ACLatitude;
    double ACLongitude;
    double ACAltitude;
    double ACAltitudeAccuracy;
    NSString *ACLocality;
    NSString *ACAdministrativeArea;
    NSString *ACCountry;
}  
@property (nonatomic)double ACLatitude;  
@property (nonatomic)double ACLongitude;  
@property (nonatomic)double ACAltitude;  
@property (nonatomic)double ACAltitudeAccuracy;  
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *ACLocality;  
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *ACAdministrativeArea;  
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *ACCountry;
@end
```

Comment: you are referencing a variable that has been deallocated when it moves to the background

Comment: What kind of variables get deallocated when the app moves to background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a **weak** property where you should have a **strong**. Look through your properties and change it to strong.

If you are using instance variables (they are now auto synthesized with xcode) such as `someVariable` that you access it with `self.someVariable` so it is retained. Without using the `self.` you are bypassing the setter and the `retain` is not being set on the variable.

Comment: Thanks Bot.The app doesn't use ARC, so the properties used are actually retain rather than weak. Don't think that I'm missing a retain, and definitely not on the actual variable that it's complaining about.

Comment: what variable is it complaining about? Can you post the code it is complaining about as well as where you are instantiating the variable?

Comment: @Andrew doesn't look like you are referencing the variable with `self.locn.blah` also make sure when you are setting `locn` that you are using `self.locn = ...`

Comment: @Andrew good to hear, i updated my answer to explain it a bit better.

Comment: Okay that was today's **dumb** mistake - hope it didn't take up too much of your time @Bot

Comment: @Andrew no problem, if it resolved the issue make sure to mark it so others with the same issue can find it.